# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: a.csv

Tags: python

I have shown the problem below. I would be glad if you help.

Contents of temp file = a.csv, b.csv, c.csv, d.csv, e.csv

```
import os

dirs = []
for i in os.listdir["C:/users/okay/temp/"]
    dirs.append(i)

for file in dirs:
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df)
    pq.write_table(table,target,filesystem=hdfs)
```

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory : 'a.csv'

Comment: Try to `print(file)` before opening it. You'll see that you store only filenames, not full paths to files

Comment: Yes i noticed, what should i do?